# Exposing a method implementation for users to modify

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm currently making a closed-source game, but would like to give it modding capabilities. In particular there is one file, StatData.cs, which stores a large dictionary of formulae and statistics which I would love to expose to mod makers.

This dictionary is generated in the StatData constructor, which is the method I'd like to expose:

```
public StatData()
{
    AddDerivedStatDefinition(
        "mass",                                                          //Key
        "Mass",                                                          //Printable Name
        "Determines how much stuff there is in the thing",               //Printable Description
        0,                                                               //Lower Limit
        float.MaxValue,                                                  //Upper Limit
        1.0f,                                                            //Mutation Rate
        delegate(Genome genome, BodyPlan bodyPlan, Phenotype phenotype)  //delegate to be stored in DerivedStatDefinition object
        {
            return bodyplan.Volume * phenotype.Skin.Density;             //Formula
        } 
    );

   //snipped: 700 lines worth of similar definitions...
}
```

(note: `bodyplan.Volume` and `phenotype.Skin.Density` are both accessors which retrieve other stats also defined in this same constructor)

While exposing the descriptions, limits and mutation rate would be easy (simply import them from a flat file or via XML, rather than hardcoding them), the formula delegates are a more complex problem.

I've looked into plugin architecture, but am a little confused by it: all the examples I found were about importing additional assemblies, not rewriting a method in an existing one. I want the users to be able to modify the formula's that are already defined, not import additional objects. It's probable I'm missing something simple, which is why I'm asking. :)

What would be the recommended strategy for exposing this code?

Comment: Importing additional assemblies is what you need to do. If your program sees that an additional assembly is imported, it can ignore the built-in code, can it not?

Answer (score 0):

May you have to simple use interface for implementing strategy pattern with default implementation?

Comment: This is a viable option - some example code on how to approach this would make it a good answer.